# json_encode with a multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, multidimensional-array, json

I've been looking at `json_encode` tips for a bit, and haven't been able to figure out yet what I'm trying to do.

I've built a php function that takes a CSV file and dumps the data into a multidimensional array (I am 99% sure this is correct, at least). I need to then take the data from the array, and put it into a line graph. Here's my PHP code that retrieves the data from the CSV (and adds a value at the end that is a calculation of 2 of the other values within the array):

```
<?php

function readCSV($csvFile) {
    $file_handle=fopen($csvFile,'r');
    while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
        $line_of_text[]=fgetcsv($file_handle,1024);
    }
    fclose($file_handle);
    return $line_of_text;
}

// Set path to CSV file
$csvFile='./example.csv';

$csv=readCSV($csvFile);
array_push($csv[0], "Percentage");
$headers = array_shift($csv);
$i=0;
foreach ($csv as $record) {
    $Perc = $record[2] / $record[3];
    $Perc = $Perc * 100;
    $Perc = round ($Perc, 2);
    array_push($csv[$i], $Perc);
    $j=0;
    $i++;
}
foreach ($csv as $key => $row) {
    $year[$key] = $row[0];
}
array_multisort($year, SORT_ASC, $csv);

//print_r($csv);
echo json_encode($csv);

?>
```

That echo gives me an array with the following results:

```
[["2008","41","412","525","125.2",78.48],["2009","33","393","571","99.9",68.83],["2010","33","450","679","91.9",66.27],["2012","37","400","583","105.8",68.61],["2013","55","450","659","115.1",68.29]]
```

The first key is the year. In my graph, I need to chart based on the year on the x-axis, and I need to chart key 1, 5, and 6 (all based on year). I have not been able to figure out how to do this.

The format for the graph is something like this:

```
var d1 = [[0, 3], [4, 8], [8, 5], [12, 13]];

var d1 = [[2009, 33], [2010, 33], [2012, 37], [2013, 55]];
var d2 = [[2009, 99.9], [2010, 91.9], [2012, 105.8], [2013, 115.1]];
var d3 = [[2009, 68.83], [2010, 66.27], [2012, 68.61], [2013, 68.29]];
```

where the first value in each set is the x-axis, the 2nd value is the y-axis.

any help would be MUCH appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not entirely understanding yet what you're asking. How does the `var d1 = []` array relate to the data from your JSON? Is that just a template for the format your graph expects? How does the year relate to that template? You mention you need to chart the year on the X, so is that as `var d1 = [[2008, 3],[2009, 8]...]` ?

Comment: The var d1 is the template for the dashboard I am using. If there are multiple lines on the graph, they would be var d2, var d3 etc. That part is in javascript. So (in theory) to get my php array there, I'd need to do something like: var d1 = <?php readCSV() ?>; I THINK? Sorry, completely new to all this.

Comment: Can you post an example of what the `d1` array should look like in JavaScript when populated with the actual values from your JSON?

Comment: I can. I will have 3 variables (d1, d2, d3):

    `var d1 = [[2009, 33], [2010, 33], [2012, 37], [2013, 55]];
    var d2 = [[2009, 99.9], [2010, 91.9], [2012, 105.8], [2013, 115.1]];
    var d3 = [[2009, 68.83], [2010, 66.27], [2012, 68.61], [2013, 68.29]];`

Comment: Ok, now we're getting somewhere. So what you want to do is transform your original JSON into 3 arrays with the year, and `[1],[5],[6]` respectively?  Do you want the PHP to output the JavaScript?

Comment: I need to be able to reference the php within the javascript, if that makes sense?

Comment: That means you need to write out the JavaScript from PHP. Hang on - I'm writing an answer.

Comment: This looks fantastic. I was mistaken, a little, though. The javascript part (declaring variables d1, d2, d3, etc) happens in the javascript portion of the code. I just need to assign the variables the proper array values. Shouldn't take me much to get there.

Comment: hrmm.... I'm getting a Notice: Uninitialized string offset: error.

Comment: What is the full error? The code as written below produces no errors.

Comment: Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 4 in graph.php on line 269.
line 268-270: `foreach ($year as $y) {
     $temp[] = array($y[0], $y[$key]);
   }`

Comment: Also, I don't know if it makes a difference or not, but the last key is a percentage calculated by [2]/[3]. When I echo the array, that value isn't in quotes, whereas the rest of the values show up in quotes: `[["2008","36","475","670","120.1",70.9],["2009","33","393","571","99.9",68.83],["2010","33","450","679","91.9",66.27],["2012","37","400","583","105.8",68.61],["2013","55","450","659","115.1",68.29]]`

Didn't know if that would cause a problem?

Comment: My edit from a bit ago didn't take. Here's the output of my code: `var d1 = [["2","0"],["2","0"],["2","0"],["2","0"],["2","0"]];
var d2 = [["2",""],["2",""],["2",""],["2",""],["2",""]];
var d3 = [["2",""],["2",""],["2",""],["2",""],["2",""]];`

Also, I tried running this locally (as opposed to the dev server), and I do not get the error.

Comment: Oh I think I used the wrong variable name for your context. Where I was acting on $year you should actually be using $csv in the foreach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before encoding the JSON, you have already successfully sorted your array `$year` with `array_multisort()`.  The next thing to do is to iterate it 3 times, one each for your three output variables and produce the 2D array for each one.  Then after you have those, you can use PHP to write out the JavaScript and call `json_encode()` on the individual arrays.

```
// You already sorted $year how you need it
array_multisort($year, SORT_ASC, $csv);

// This will store your final output
$mapped_values = array();

// You want the keys 1,4,5
foreach (array(1,4,5) as $key) {
  $temp = array();
  // Loop over each year array and make a sub-array of year,key
  // 2008, 2008, 2010....
  foreach ($csv as $y) {
    // intval() & floatval() prevent the output as strings to JSON...
    $temp[] = array(intval($y[0]), floatval($y[$key]);
  }
  // Append the structure to the outer result
  // Each of these corresponds to one of the keys 1,4,5...
  $mapped_values[] = $temp;
}

// Write it as output:
foreach ($mapped_values as $varnum => $js_var) {
  // To get the d1, d2, d3
  $num = $varnum + 1;
  // Write a var dN = JSON...
  // json_encode() will produce the appropriate output
  echo "var d{$num} = " . json_encode($js_var) . ";\n";
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
var d1 = [[2008,41],[2009,33],[2010,33],[2012,37],[2013,55]];
var d2 = [[2008,125.2],[2009,99.9],[2010,91.9],[2012,105.8],[2013,115.1]];
var d3 = [[2008,78.48],[2009,68.83],[2010,66.27],[2012,68.61],[2013,68.29]];
```